# Is there a way that regex rules can be disabled (or enabled) in Apache?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an .htaccess file that's using several rewrite rules. These rules aren't working on a server I'm testing on, but do they work on another server. I tested using a rule that doesn't use a regex, and that seems to work. Is there any way that regex rules can be disabled (or enabled) in Apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, regular expressions are fundamental for mod_rewrite. But it might be possible that your servers have different versions and don’t use the same regular expression engine (POSIX ERE since 1.2, PCRE since 2.0).

Comment: What's a quick and easy way to determine which engine the server is using?

Comment: @Calvin L: My post is a little ambiguous. mod_rewrite supports only one regular expression engine. The version of Apache tells you what engine is used.

Comment: Thanks Gumbo, turns out the live server is on Apache 1.3.41, and my local server is on 2.2.11. Oy! Thank you so much, that really helped.